# DateTime variable is empty

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime, type-conversion

I want to have an if condition for empty values. You can see below my variable "endedAt", which is a DateTime variable. However, it has some blank values which take the value 'NaT'. Now I want to create a condition for these empty values. But I do not know how to refer to them. I have tried the following:

```
1. if(df.iloc[i]['endedAt'] == 'NaT'):
2. if(df.iloc[i]['endedAt'] == ''):
```

But none of them works and the things I have within the if statement are not executed.

EXAMPLE DATA:

**endedAt**

NaT

2018-11-20 01:10:43

2018-11-19 20:21:57

2018-11-19 20:06:23

2018-11-19 04:05:36

Comment: you can use a command like  `if pd.isnull(d) for d in df1['endedAt']`

Comment: Use "if a in b" if you are comparing two string('NaT'). In 2nd case it might be possible it have space , i would suggest use strip() function. Also check what value you getting and what's type of value. It could be possible return value is not of string type.

Comment: Thank you Yogesh it worked, could you explain what you are doing though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.Nat` like `if df.iloc[i]['endedAt'] is pd.NaT:`:

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.to_datetime([
        None,
        pd.Timestamp("2018-11-20 01:10:43"),
        pd.Timestamp("2018-11-19 20:21:57"),
        pd.Timestamp("2018-11-19 20:06:23"),
        pd.Timestamp("2018-11-19 04:05:36"),
        ])
df = pd.DataFrame({"endedAt": dt})

print(df)

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['endedAt'] is pd.NaT:
        print("\nNaT row index:", i)
```

**Out:**

```
              endedAt
0                 NaT
1 2018-11-20 01:10:43
2 2018-11-19 20:21:57
3 2018-11-19 20:06:23
4 2018-11-19 04:05:36

NaT row index: 0
```